# Forcing(?) SASS to output same valued declarations as a single declaration

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to get several CSS declarations with the same value to be declared on a single declaration. I've come across this problem a few times, [one example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74104717/sass-outputting-to-the-same-declaration/74133123#74133123), but this time is a more simple example.

Desired output:

```css
.flex-col-1 div.pagebuilder-column-group,
.flex-col-2 div.pagebuilder-column-group,
.flex-col-3 div.pagebuilder-column-group,
.flex-col-4 div.pagebuilder-column-group,
.flex-col-5 div.pagebuilder-column-group,
.flex-col-6 div.pagebuilder-column-group,
.flex-col-7 div.pagebuilder-column-group,
.flex-col-8 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

Current SCSS:

```scss
@mixin initial-gap() {
  @each $rows in $row-amounts {
    .flex-col-#{$rows} {
      & div.pagebuilder-column-group {
        gap: 1rem;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Current output:

```css
.flex-col-1 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-col-2 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-col-3 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-col-4 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-col-5 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-col-6 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-col-7 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-col-8 div.pagebuilder-column-group {
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

The only way I've found, thus far, is to implicitly declare them in the mixin. Any other ways of achieving the desired CSS??

eg.

```scss
@mixin initial-gap() {
  .flex-col-1,
  .flex-col-2,
  .flex-col-3,
  .flex-col-4,
  .flex-col-5,
  .flex-col-6,
  .flex-col-7,
  .flex-col-8 {
    & div.pagebuilder-column-group {
      gap: 1rem;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan, THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I HAD BEEN STRUGGLING WITH THIS FOR A FEW WEEKS AND WASN'T PUZZLING IT TOGETHER, IT MAKES SO MUCH SENSE NOW!!!  CHEEEEEEEERSSSS. sorry for caps.

Comment: You're adorable.

Comment: @Lisa haha thank you, help me get better at SASS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559099/grouping-selectors-inside-of-a-loop-using-sass).

```
%foo {
    gap: 1rem; }

@for $i from 1 through 8 {
    .flex-col-#{$i}  div.pagebuilder-column-group {
        @extend %foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally . TYSM!